# argument in for each

Tags: c#, foreach

My original line is

```
foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(7)
```

I would like to replace the "7" with an argument of a commandline:

```
foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip({0}), args[1])
```

this is having wrong syntax?

Comment: Imagine 7 is a variable called `fileNumber` with a type of `int`. Now, put an argument (`args[1]`, which is a `string`) into the `fileNumber` variable. It must be converted to an `int` first. Then use `fileNumber` in place of 7.

Comment: The syntax you're trying to write looks like `string.Format(...)` syntax.  That methods outputs a string, and `Skip(...)` takes an integer, not a string.  C# is strongly typed, and doesn't do an implicit conversion from `string` to `int` for you (if you're used to other languages, you might think it would)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `args[1]` is a string, what you want is:

```
foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(int.Parse(args[1])))
```

it should be noted there is no error checking here, so if `args[1]` is not a number, you will get unhandled exception.

Answer (score 2):

```
int number;

if (!int.TryParse(args[1], out number))
    throw new ArgumentException("The entered parameter is not a number.");

foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(number)))
{
    // Whatever you do with each file
}
```

`int.TryParse` returns false if the given argument string is not a number.

Comment: You can't cast a string to an integer.

Comment: BTW, it wasn't my down-vote :)  Put your `int.TryParse ...` in an if block, throw a useful error message, and I'd up-vote the corrected answer.

Comment: Looks like the original poster prefers the above solution without exception handling.